# table direction when I save HTML as word document

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I have simple html code that I want to save it as .doc document.

When I save it as an html document, table direction is `'ltr'` and it is correct but when I save as `.doc`, table direction is `'rtl'`,how can I fix it?

I need all my elements to be `rtl` except the table.

this is my code:

```
<html  dir="rtl">
<body>
<table dir="ltr">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>
this is a test
</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Save it as .html/.doc USING WHAT?

Comment: in my web application I use HTMLeditor and I need to save the content as .doc